# what container we can use for global and environment variables in Jmeter for API testing

Tags: jmeter, jmeter-plugins, jmeter-3.2

I am trying to use Jmeter for API automation testing.

But Jmeter hasn't provided any separate containers for global and environment variables similarly like SOAP-UI and Postman.

I tried to use property file which also shared among all the JSR223 throughout the project but property having many others keys too and I haven't got any option by which I can delete key which been initiated once. Moreover, I can update the value too which seems most preferable to use

Below code I am using to set and get the values

```
props.put("shubhamKey", "shubhamValue")

props.get("shubhamKey")
```

I can also update it using same key

```
props.put("shubhamKey", "shubhamNewValue")
```

But as I said we can't delete key once initiated and it seems dangerous to delete from properties as it has many other keys too which may be required by Jmeter internally

After seeing too many things I have seen "User Defined Variables" where I can specify my key-value pairs. I am able to get the value using below code:

```
vars.get("shubhamLocalVariable")
```

But I am not able to set the value using below code:

```
vars.put("shubhamUserKeyagain","shubhamUservalue")
```

neither I got any option by which I further update it or delete it.

so Is there any feasible thing to store variables in Jmeter which can be easily created/deleted/updated using the code and can even call by other containers like HTTP Request.

Moreover I also want a container which preserve the values so the next iteration and next time (any time like other day) it will start with latest values

User Parameters

[image]

Jsr223

[image]

Any workaround will be helpful and appreciated in advance

Answer (score 0):

As for me, I'm using a JSR223 Sampler at the begining of every Thread.
And for me it works:

```java
vars.put("checksums_1","")
vars.put("checksums_2","")
vars.put("checksums_3","")
```

Comment: you mean JSR223 Assertion right? because vars.put("checksums_1","") is not working for me

Comment: @ShubhamJain No, sampler, like [this](https://imgur.com/a/vwxlK) 
What version of jMeter are you using? 
Do you use groovy?

Comment: JSR223 Sampler is also not working for me. I have posted another question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48499435/how-to-set-variable-and-its-value-in-jmeter-container-like-user-parameter-using

Answer (score 0):

Firstly you can delete properties by using:

```
props.remove("shubhamKey");
```

And if you use specific prefix/suffix it shouldn't effect JMeter internally.

[User Defined Variables](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#User_Defined_Variables) isn't the best way to handle dynamic values, it's used for static variables

> Note that all the UDV elements in a test plan - no matter where they are - are processed at the start.

But you can set variable by string or variable or function, e.g:

[image]

For defining variables during a test run, see [User Parameters](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#User_Parameters) which use similar assignments.

Comment: Thanks I will try it ... Currently I m out of office ... Thanks for your response

Comment: Can you please specify some code by which I can get and set value in User Parameters

Comment: exactly the same as User Define Variables

Comment: nup it is not working .. I have added 2 screenshots in my question. please do refer same

Comment: Put User Parameters under Get Sampler to execute once before Sampler

Comment: no it is not working for me .. I have uploaded my sample project here .. can you please check and send me back the project so I can understand the issue .. here is the URL https://ufile.io/7r6tk .. it will help

Comment: I have tried to put User Parameter before JSR223 Assertion, After it, even outer side but nothing working out,.. can you please explain the way which is working for you?